# How to avoid NullPointerException when initalizing ShapeRenderer at LibGdx

Tags: java, maven, libgdx

Could you please explain why I get NPE when initializing a ShapeRenderer? I try to get familiar with LibGdx, started at the basics, but I stuck at the beginning.

I have 2 classes which are:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private ShapeRenderer shape;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        shape = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shape.circle(50, 50, 50);
        shape.end();
    }
}
```

and the main class, including the entry point:

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyGdxGame game = new MyGdxGame();
        game.create();
        game.render();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I got NPE with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.loadShader(ShaderProgram.java:204)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.compileShaders(ShaderProgram.java:183)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.<init>(ShaderProgram.java:166)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.createDefaultShader(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:241)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.<init>(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:55)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.<init>(ShapeRenderer.java:116)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.<init>(ShapeRenderer.java:111)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.<init>(ShapeRenderer.java:107)
    at game.MyGdxGame.<init>(MyGdxGame.java:10)
    at game.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:6)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

One important thing, I'm using Maven, since I don't know much about Gradle, may it cause problem? Anyway, my Pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example.mylibgdx</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylibgdx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <com.badlogicgames.gdx.version>1.11.0</com.badlogicgames.gdx.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gdx-nightlies</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdx</artifactId>
            <version>${com.badlogicgames.gdx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not Maven, but **the way you start your application**.
In your main method you create a game and start rendering while the libGdx features are not initialized yet. The usual way to start your application would look somewhat like this (for desktop applications):

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
    config.setForegroundFPS(60);
    config.setTitle("My GDX Game");
    new Lwjgl3Application(new MyGdxGame(), config);
}
```

This way your game is created, but libGdx is responsible for calling the render method of you game class when the libGdx backend is ready.

---

If you download the libGdx setup tool ([link to download](https://libgdx.com/wiki/start/project-generation)) and create a project you can select the types of application you want your game to be runnable on (desktop, android, ios, html). The tool will generate a main class in each project, that starts the game correctly.